# Is Date.now() in local milliseconds since epoch, or milliseconds since epoch in UTC time

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, utc

I have the impression `Date.now()` is milliseconds since epoch in our *local* time zone. If that's the case, how can I get milliseconds since epoch in *UTC* time?  This would be the long way I guess:

```
new Date(new Date().toUTCString()).getTime()
```

is there a faster way?

Comment: Also, I get the impression that `Date.now() === new Date().getTime()` but maybe not..

Comment: *All* representations of time since the Unix epoch are in UTC, as the Unix epoch itself is defined in terms of UTC.  Any representation of "local milliseconds since epoch" would by definition need to use a *local* epoch.  That also would introduce problems due to daylight saving time and other local time discrepancies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) and [`new Date().getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) use UTC for time representation.

Answer (score 1):

From MDN:

> The Date.now() method returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)

Comment: the time elapsed since Jan 1, 1970 UTC, but from what time zone's perspective

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking ... UTC doesn't refer to a specific timezone. It is a universal time standard around which all other time zones are based by offsets. If you want the name of a timezone that uses UTC with no offset, that is GMT.

Comment: In other words, it’s the milliseconds elapsed since the epoch UTC time to the current UTC time

Comment: MDN is not normative, [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-time-values-and-time-range) is. ;-)